# How could I use Theme.AppCompat while adding support v7 without resources

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-support-library

I'm trying to set ActionBar in my android application for targets 8-18 using the support libraries. With the official statement of Android, the use of ActionBar is based on Theme.AppCompat of support library v7. I followed the official guide http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html (section "**Adding libraries with resources**" using **eclipse**) and the ActionBar was well performed. But since I need to avoid adding libraries with resources, I want to export a .jar file of support library v7 and add it into lib folder of my app, the android:theme="@android:style/Theme.AppCompat.Light" causes error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@android:style/Theme.AppCompat.Light'). Also, if I simply add the android-support-v7.jar, I'm not allowed either to use Theme.AppCompat. So anyone could figure out how to export .jar of the support library v7 resources which could be added in the way of "adding library without resources" to allow the Theme.AppCompat? Thanks in advance.

Comment: "But since I need to avoid adding libraries with resources" -- ummmm... why?

Comment: @CommonsWare just beacause it's teamwork on Github and the others think it's not logical that they should pull the project and then they still need to set up the library dependencies...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So anyone could figure out how to export .jar of the support library v7 resources which could be added in the way of "adding library without resources" to allow the Theme.AppCompat?

That is not possible. AppCompat and ActionBarSherlock -- the two leading action bar backports -- make very heavy use of resources. It is not just `Theme.AppCompat` (or ABS's equivalent, `Theme.Sherlock`), but colors and dimensions and drawables and layouts and strings and more. You can tell that by looking at the source code of each project.

You are welcome to attempt to write your own action bar backport library that somehow eschews resources.

Or, if you happen to be using Android Studio and the new Gradle-based build system, simply require the AppCompat AAR file, and the resources will be taken care of for you.